# Web scraping Yahoo finance

Tags: vba, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get the sector and Industry from yahoo finance:

Link: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MWET3.SA?p=MWET3.SA&.tsrc=fin-srch?p

```
YF = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Paper & ".SA?p=" & Paper & ".SA&.tsrc=fin-srch"
appIE.Navigate YF
'Web scraping

Set Sector = appIE.Document.getElementByClassName("Fw(600)")

Worksheets("Bovespa").Rows(i).Columns(11) = Sector
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be using *both* chrome and IE?  You first need to decide which browser to use, and work from there... If you want to use Chrome you can't automate it the same way as IE - you would need to use (eg) Selenium.   And it's `getElementByClassName` not `getElementByClass`

Comment: Ok I correct that.

Comment: I think it's `getElementsByClassName` (plural) as it returns a collection.You then need to use an index position to choose the item e.g. `getElementsByClassName("Fw(600)")[0]`